# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_multiple_model'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when trying to start runserver
it give me this error, I have no idea why, it was working fine before

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_multiple_model'

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-RGL58hqa/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'drf_multiple_model'
```

Comment: pip install django-rest-multiple-models

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Django Rest Framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework) provides some incredible tools for serializing data, but sometimes you need to combine many serializers and/or models into a single API call. drf-multiple-model is an app designed to do just that.

([from the documentation](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Well, I guess you found your answer but if someone else has the same issue, perhaps this is what is missing:

```
pip install django-rest-multiple-models
```

Make sure to add `drf_multiple_model` to your INSTALLED_APPS and then simply import the view into any `views.py`.